# JavaScript file served as blank

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure whats going on here.  Originally I had some code in `script.js` but now it's refactored and ready to be in its own file.  So after I was done refactoring I moved the code to `base.js`.  Here is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <title>Draw</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="libraries/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas">
    HTML5 Canvas not supported.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason though, `base.js` shows up as empty in chrome developer tools and `script.js` complains that it can't find the prototype defined in `base.js`.

I know that the URL is good because I purposely miss-spelled it and in the developer console it yells at me about not being able to find it until I correct the spelling.  I know its not being cached because I've cleared my cache.  Finally, I tried just changing the name to `base_prototype.js` and it works.

Why does this happen?

EDIT: Adding script.js base.js

```
//script.js
/**
 * Created by carlos on 5/20/15.
 */
var myBase;

$(function() {
    myBase = new Base(document.getElementById("canvas"));
    myBase.draw(minDim());



});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    myBase.draw(minDim());
});

function minDim(){
    return Math.min($(window).height(),$(window).width());

}

//base.js
/**
 * Created by carlos on 5/23/15.
 */
function Base(canvas){
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.grids = 40;
    this.canvasSize = 0;
    this.draw = function(size){
        this.canvasSize = size;
        this.canvas.width = size;
        this.canvas.height = size;
        $( this.canvas ).height(size);
        $( this.canvas ).width();

        this.drawZeroMatrixStockGrid(0,this.grids,0,this.grids);

        this.context.stroke();
    };

    this.drawZeroMatrixStockGrid = function (startX, endX, startY, endY){
        var adjust = this.grids/2;
        this.drawMatrixStockGrid(startX-adjust , endX-adjust , startY-adjust, endY-adjust);
    };
    this.drawMatrixStockGrid = function(startX, endX, startY, endY){

        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.transform(.5, -.5, .5, .5, this.canvasSize/2, this.canvasSize/2);
        this.context.scale(1,1);
        for(var x = startX;x<endX + 1 ;x++){
            this.context.moveTo(this.getXCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,x),this.getYCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,startY));
            this.context.lineTo(this.getXCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,x),this.getYCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,endY));
        }

        for(var y = startY;y<endY + 1;y++){
            this.context.moveTo(this.getXCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,startX),this.getYCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,y));
            this.context.lineTo(this.getXCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,endX),this.getYCoord(this.canvasSize,this.grids,y));
        }

    };


    /**
     * assumes a square canvas
     * TODO use global vars to clean signature
     * TODO memoize
     * */
    this.getXCoord = function (canvasSize, grids, coord){
        var delta = canvasSize/(grids);
        return delta*coord;
    };
    this.getYCoord = function(canvasSize, grids, coord){
        var delta = canvasSize/(grids);
        return delta*coord;
    };


}
```

Comment: Does this only happen in google chrome?

Comment: Do you have any browser addons/plugins? Try disabling those in case something like adblock is blocking the script.

Comment: @OliverBarnwell Happens in safari too.  @ j08691 I dont have any browser plugins that do that.

Comment: Got a link we can see?

Comment: Its only at localhost right now...  I wasn't planning to put it up public yet... sorry

Comment: can you show code in script.js and base.js?

Comment: Minor side note, `http-equiv="cache-control"` isn't valid in HTML5.

Comment: What happens when you view the file in the browser as opposed to in the DOM inspector?

Comment: @SteveHynding viewing with http://localhost:8080/base.js is just a blank screen.

Comment: Sounds a lot like your server has a problem with the base.js filename for some reason

Comment: What is your server setup? Is it possible base.js is being overwritten by the response handler? I'm assuming navigating to the file via file:// protocol works correctly

Comment: @SteveHynding That was it.  I have a REST controller registered.  Mapped "{[/base],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.clashalytics.domain.base.Base com.clashalytics.domain.base.controller.BaseController.base(java.lang.String) post as answer so you can get da points

Comment: @SteveHynding Go ahead and write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can view the file locally via file:// but not http://, the problem is most likely coming from the server setup. The response handler can overwrite your static files without warning and send successful status calls.

As you discovered through our comments, the REST controller is indeed mapping GET requests on the "[/base]" pattern, overwriting any attempts at static files matching the asset name. Changing the file name is the quickest path to resolution, at least on the front-end.

Cheers!